# How to automatically add other resource rows?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, localization, resources

I am currently localizing my app with Visual Studio.

I have a couple of resource files now, but everytime I add new resource row (translation) on the main `.resx` file, I have to manually add those rows to all other `.resx` files.

I find that very tedious. Isn't there an automated way for this?

Answer (score 0):

When using Visual Studio 2012 all you should have to do is use the Resource GUI and it should update all the files you need. It should look like this

http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=add+resource+string+visual+studio+2012&qs=n&form=QBIR&pq=add+resource+string+visual+studio+2012&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=#view=detail&id=E13CE5F32BC2141CE18B0599B879E61531FE8541&selectedIndex=54

Also if you want help updating all the strings of the same value in a code base ReSharper does a nice job of this.